# How to remove duplicate values from array - php

Tags: php

I am trying to remove duplicate and empty values from array with `array_unique()` function, but getting wrong output.

Data:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array  (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 
            [3] => 108
            [4] => 
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 
            [3] => 108
            [4] => 
            [5] => 101
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 108
            [3] => 
        )
)
```

PHP:

```
$array = array_filter($userids);
$arrays = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
print_r($arrays);
```

nothing happens with SORT_REGULAR - output comes same as raw data, and without SORT_REGULAR this output is coming:

```
$array = array_filter($userids);
$arrays = array_unique($array);
print_r($arrays);
```

output:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 
            [3] => 108
            [4] => 
        )
    )
```

output I am looking for:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 108
            [2] => 101 
        )
)
```

Comment: I don't think it does a nested search

Comment: @ADyson any solution to get unique values in an array?

Comment: Since you want unique values across several sub-arrays, I'd maybe suggest combining all those into a single array as the first step

Comment: Are you looking for something like this ? https://onlinephp.io/c/28014

Comment: You can flatten a multidimensional array using: `$array = array_merge(...$array);`. Then you'll get one single array with all values, which you can run unique and filter on that one.

Comment: @M.Eriksson it worked, thanks allot for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those array functions only works on a single level. If you flatten the array (adding all elements in a single element array), it should be pretty straight forward.

Flatten the array

```
$array = array_merge(...$array);
```

***Note:** This method works fine for flattening indexed arrays like in your example, but not for associative arrays where any of the sub arrays contains the same keys.*

Then filter out all empty

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

and then remove all duplicates

```
$array = array_unique($array);
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$array = array_unique(array_filter(array_merge(...$array)));
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/pEJAJ